# How to save the select2 items after making it sortable

Tags: javascript, laravel, jquery-select2, voyager, sortablejs

I'm trying to make the following select2 selection field in laravel voyager admin panel sortable with sortable.js.

```
                                <select id="selected-items" class="form-control select2" name="selected_items[]" multiple="multiple">
                                    <?php $default = null; ?>
                                    @if(isset($items))
                                        @if (! empty($selectedValues))
                                            @foreach($selectedValues as $selectedVal)
                                                @foreach($items as $option)
                                                    @if ( $selectedVal == $option->$itemId )
                                                        <option value="{{ $option->$itemId }}" selected="selected">{{ $option->$itemTitle }} {{ $option->slug ? '(' . $option->slug. ')' : '' }}</option>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endforeach
                                            @foreach($items as $option)
                                                @if ( ! in_array($option->$itemId, $selectedValues) )
                                                    <option value="{{ $option->$itemId }}">{{ $option->$itemTitle }} {{ $option->slug ? '(' . $option->slug. ')' : '' }}</option>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        @else
                                            @foreach($items as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option->$itemId }}">{{ $option->$itemTitle }} {{ $option->slug ? '(' . $option->slug. ')' : '' }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                </select>
I
```

use the following code

```
            var el = document.querySelector('.select2-selection__rendered');
            var sortable = Sortable.create(el);
```

it actually makes the selected options sortable and draggable. but it doesn't save. when I close the page or add a new item it goes back to the first state that it was.

I tried storing in the localStorage... but still the order of the selected_items[] does not change... I think the order of the selected_items[] needs to change in order for this to get saved .

```
        var select2List = document.querySelector('.select2-selection__rendered');
        Sortable.create(select2List, {
        group: "localStorage-example",
        store: {
            /**
             * Get the order of elements. Called once during initialization.
             * @param   {Sortable}  sortable
             * @returns {Array}
             */
            get: function (sortable) {
                var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);
                return order ? order.split('|') : [];
            },

            /**
             * Save the order of elements. Called onEnd (when the item is dropped).
             * @param {Sortable}  sortable
             */
            set: function (sortable) {
                var order = sortable.toArray();
                localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join('|'));
            }
        }
    })
```